# How to resolve "Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, jboss7.x

I have recently Upgraded my application.
Upgradation details:
 - Java 6 to Java 8
 - Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 3.6.10
 - Spring 2.5 to Spring 4
 - JBoss EAP 6 to JBoss EAP 7

I am trying to save some values which include some text values and files(Clob). The data is getting saved but I am getting an exception on the next hibernate operation.

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$3$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2184)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2559)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2495)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2822)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at com.honeywell.cdd.dao.RptGrpDAOImpl.removeUnConfigGrpMTDT(RptGrpDAOImpl.java:2373)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:112)
    ... 68 more

 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: could not reset reader
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy.resetIfNeeded(ClobProxy.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy.getCharacterStream(ClobProxy.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy.invoke(ClobProxy.java:121)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.getCharacterStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.SerializableClobProxy.invoke(SerializableClobProxy.java:74)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132.getCharacterStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:114)
    ... 98 more
```

I am not able to find out exact cause of this exception.

**> The Same Code is working fine in the older configuration**

Answer (score 0):

> *"The Same Code is working fine in the older configuration"*

is not really relevant ... unless you want to submit a but report to someone.

Lets look at what the nested exception:

> `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: could not reset reader`

The stacktrace indicates that something is calling `getCharacterStream()` on a Clob proxy and that is failing when the proxy attempts to reset the proxy's reader.  The failure is (presumably) occurring because the JDBC object wrapped by the proxy doesn't allow a reader to be reset.

So why is this happening?

Again ... presumably ... something in your application has tried to call `getCharacterStream()` *twice* on a `Clob` proxy.

My guess is that you are (implicitly) using `Clob` objects as if they were in-memory files ... to avoid reading them when you don't need to.  Except that sometimes you need to, and this is interfering with the persisting.